# How to resolve the issue with TimeBasedTriggerPolicy in log4j2

Tags: logging, log4j, log4j2

I have configured log4j2 as below.
Though it is generating the file properly but latest logs(today current logs) are also being written into the old log files along with new file.

> ` 
>
> D:/Java_Work
>
> ```
>     <Appenders>
>             <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
>                     <PatternLayout
>                             pattern="[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %class{36} %L %M - %msg%xEx%n" />
>             </Console>
>             <RollingFile name="MyFile" fileName="${log-path}/app.log"
>                     filePattern="${log-path}/app-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log">
>                     <PatternLayout>
>                             <pattern>[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %class{36}
>                                     %L %M - %msg%xEx%n</pattern>
>                     </PatternLayout>
>                     <Policies>
>                             <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1" modulate="true"/>
>                     </Policies>
>                     <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="10" />
>             </RollingFile>
>    
>
>     </Appenders>
>     <Loggers>
>             <Root level="debug">
>                     <AppenderRef ref="Console" level="debug" />
>                     <AppenderRef ref="MyFile" level="debug" />                      
>             </Root>
>             
>     </Loggers>
> ```
>
> `

Comment: What version of Log4j 2 are you using? Many bugs have been fixed so I would recommend trying with the latest release. If you continue to have problems I would recommend adding status="DEBUG" to your Configuration element and then creating a Jira issue for Log4j with those logs attached.

Comment: Iam using 2.8 version

Comment: Yeah - 2.8 is 3 years old now. There have been 14 releases since then.